Warning `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` after execution with the plugin `exec-maven-plugin`
How can I execute a Java main class which implements a few queries with the embedded PostgreSQL created with com.opentable.components:otj-pg-embedded:0.13.4 from test scope using the exec-maven-plugin?
At the end of the execution I get the following error message:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  34.374 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-12-12T15:01:58Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils
    at com.opentable.db.postgres.embedded.EmbeddedPostgres.close (EmbeddedPostgres.java:376)
    at com.opentable.db.postgres.embedded.EmbeddedPostgres$1.run (EmbeddedPostgres.java:342)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.URLClassLoaderBuilder$ExecJavaClassLoader.loadClass (URLClassLoaderBuilder.java:198)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:527)
    at com.opentable.db.postgres.embedded.EmbeddedPostgres.close (EmbeddedPostgres.java:376)
    at com.opentable.db.postgres.embedded.EmbeddedPostgres$1.run (EmbeddedPostgres.java:342)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:829)

Here is the configuration of the plugin, which I execute with the command clean test exec:java:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>maven</executable>
        <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
        <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
        <mainClass>example.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

I have also tried other phases but unfortunately without success.
Here are my dependencies:
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree
[INFO] com.example:example-console-app:jar:0.0.1
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:4.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:4.0.5:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:4.0.5:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.eclipse.angus:angus-activation:jar:2.0.2:runtime
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.extension:jar:4.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:jar:4.0.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.asm:jar:9.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.42.0:runtime
[INFO] +- com.example:commons-testing:jar:0.0.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.instancio:instancio-junit:jar:3.6.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.instancio:instancio-core:jar:3.6.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] |  +- com.opentable.components:otj-pg-embedded:jar:0.13.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.11:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.20:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.8.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-annotations:jar:4.1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.626 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-12-12T12:54:38+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

